# Pixel Perfect Measure approach for margins

Tags: html, css, web

In my team we have a problem that is related with the measure in pixels. When design came we start developing the components of the website following the design specifications, for instance the design said from the link to the name of the person should be 18px as you can see in the image:

[image]

but when we go to implementation and see the result we have more (or sometime less) pixel because the text itself has a height and then has the specified margin:

[image]

So in this case you end up with 23px between the two paragraphs instead of 18px that design specified and this create a defect in our backlog.

We are trying to define a best way to avoid this problems. Any suggestions?

Example:

```css
h2 {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 
}

a,  a:link, a:hover, a:active, a:visited {
    color: #6b94ff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 16px;
}
p {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 details">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 class="title-link">
                <a href="/news/updates/imds-first-ever-emba-discovery-expedition-to-vietnam/" target="_self">
                    IMD’s first-ever EMBA Discovery Expedition to Vietnam
                </a>
            </h2>
                <p class="topics">
                    Topics: <span>Economics</span>
                </p>
            <p>
                Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules.
            </p>

            <a class="promotional" href="#" target="_self">
                Read more
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: We need working code snippets that reproduce the issue or else we can't see how/why/what

Comment: Padding, margin, border, line-height, zoom factor, scale, position...

Answer (score 0):

Remove all current margins from `h2`,`a`,`p` and add this line to your code:

`a,p,h2 { line-height: 16px; margin: 0 0 18px 0 }`

You need to remove the HTML default margins and set line-height (default `1.333333`)
to your designated font-size of `16px`.

Might I add, however, that it is VERY bad practice to use fixed values for fonts as users should able to modify the HTML default font-size to meet their requirements (not all have 20/20 eyesight), `1em` or `1rem` is prefered which is `16px` by default anyway.

The proper code would be (for your example):

`a,p,h2 { line-height: 1rem; margin: 0 0 1.125rem 0 }/* calc(18/16) */`